# Write a program that first takes in word pairs that consist of a name and a phone number (both strings), separated by a comma

Tags: python, list, split

I have the following prompt:

> A contact list is a place where you can store a specific contact with other associated information such as a phone number, email address, birthday, etc. Write a program that first takes in word pairs that consist of a name and a phone number (both strings), separated by a comma. That list is followed by a name, and your program should output the phone number associated with that name. Assume the search name is always in the list.

Ex:

> If the input is: Joe,123-5432 Linda,983-4123 Frank,867-5309 Frank the
> output is: 867-5309

my code:

```
pn = str(input()).split()

search = str(input())

i=0

for i in range(len(on)):

if pn[i] == (search):

print([i+1])
```

The input is getting split into a name and number. When the code goes to check if the names are the same, it always returns false. I've tried using the `re.split()` method, but it didn't work.

Comment: `input()` already returns a string.  You don't need to keep calling `str()` on the result.

Comment: Also, you probably want to use `split(",")` if you want to split on a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You should split twice and second split char should be a comma `s.split(",")`

```
s = "Joe,123-5432 Linda,983-4123 Frank,867-5309"

for i in s.split():
    temp = i.split(",");
    print("name :", temp[0] , " number is :" , temp[1] )
```

Output

```
name : Joe  number is : 123-5432
name : Linda  number is : 983-4123
name : Frank  number is : 867-5309
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting around the comma when searching for the name:

```
pn = input().split()
search = input()

for i in pn:
  val = i.split(',')
  if val[0] == search:
    print(val[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the following things in your program to meet the basic requirements

1. Infinite loop to enter contact info until user stop entering
2. List or Dictionary to hold entered info and for searching

The code can be like following

```
contacts = {}

while True:
    info = input('Enter Contact Info or Leave empty to Stop Entering: ').split(',')
    if len(info) > 1:
        contacts[info[0]] = info[1]
    else:
        break

name = input('Enter name to search: ')
print(contacts[name])
```

**Output is following**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to store the data as an input, ask the user for a query (name of a person), and then respond with that person's phone number.

```py
# Get the data
inputs = input("Enter the input. >>> ").split(sep=" ")

# Split the data into lists
for pos in range(len(inputs)):
    inputs[pos] = inputs[pos].split(sep=",")

# Ask for a search query
query = input("Enter a name. >>> ")
# Check for the name in the first element of each item
for item in inputs:
    if item[0] == query:
        print(f"{query}'s phone number is {item[1]}.")
        break
```

A sample data input, as called in line 2:

```
Enter the input. >>> John,12313123 Bob,8712731823
```

As of the search query line of the code, your `inputs` variable looks something like: `[['John', '12313123'], ['Bob', '8712731823']]`. The program will iterate through the items of `inputs`, where each item is a list of two strings, and then check if the first item of this sub-list matches the inputted query.

Answer (score 0):

```
contact_list = input().split(sep=" ")
search_list = input()

def Convert(lst):
    res_dct = {lst[i]: lst[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)}
    return res_dct

contact_dict = Convert(contact_list)

print(contact_dict[search_list])
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I turned the user input into a dictionary with two for loops and a zip() method.  Then I just iterated over the dictionary finding the key and printing out the value.  I am pretty new to Python and this took me awhile to figure out but I know this will help someone. I am sure there are many other easier ways to write and solve this but this was how i solved it.

```
userInput = input().replace(' ', ',') # places commas where white space is in string
correct = userInput.split(',') # seperates at the commas and creates a list with everything seperated
nameChoose = input().strip() # gets user input to search a name in the future dictionary

newList1 = [] # creating a new empty list to place names in
newList2 = [] # creating a new empty list to place numbers in
for i in correct:
    newList1 = correct[0::2] # starting with first name iterating to store each name in empty list

for i in correct:
    newList2 = correct[1::2] # starting with first number iterating to store each number in empty list

numDict = dict(zip(newList1, newList2)) # merges the two list together creating a dictionary

for k, v in numDict.items(): # iterates over keys (k) and values (v) over 
    if k == nameChoose:  
        print(v)  # prints the phone number only of the name the user choose
```

Answer (score 0):

```
info = input().split(' ')  #takes string and separates by space
contacts = {}   #empty dictionary 

for pers in info:  #iterating over info list
    split = pers.split(',') 
    contacts[split[0]] = split[1]  #creating the key, value pairs
    
name = input()   #asks which name to search
print(contacts[name])  #prints value associated with key
```